# Python UnicodeEncodeError involving 'charmap' codec

Tags: python, csv

This code was working fine before but now when i try to write a list to a csv file I get this error -

```
File "C:/Users/wf5931/OneDrive - ENGIE/Documents/Python Scripts/Scrape Vehicle Reg Info/vehicleRegChecker 6.1.py", line 109, in openFile
    writer.writerow(x)

File "C:\Users\wf5931\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2082' in position 78: character maps to <undefined
```

from this:

```
with open(vehicleRegInformation, 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for x in vehicleRegInfo:
        writer.writerow(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `encoding="utf-8"` :

```
with open(vehicleRegInformation, 'w', newline='',encoding="utf-8") as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
for x in vehicleRegInfo:
    writer.writerow(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `encoding` to the file opening

```
with open(vehicleRegInformation, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as f:
```